# How to take screenshots for free in Python

Tags: python, scripting

For a university machine learning project I want to gather full-page website screenshots of ~100,000 websites.

The website URLs are located in a CSV file which I've managed to load into my Python program. I now want to loop through those URLS and screenshot the contents of the sites, and save the images locally.

After some Googling I found a few APIs such as [this one](https://screenshotapi.net) but they all have paid plans, and are quite expensive for the amount of screenshots I want to take.

Does anyone know how to take a screenshot of a website without using a paid service in Python?

Comment: https://pythonspot.com/selenium-take-screenshot/

Comment: Hope this link helps: https://pythonbasics.org/selenium-screenshot/#:~:text=Screenshots%20of%20webpages%20can%20be,is%20loaded%2C%20take%20the%20screenshot.

Comment: https://medium.com/@dschnr/using-headless-chrome-as-an-automated-screenshot-tool-4b07dffba79a